# How to update item in ListBox in WindowsForm Application in C#

Tags: winforms, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitem, selectedindexchanged

I have created a windows form application in which there is a ListBox to display items. When I click on an item it gets selected as I have implemented `lst_items_SelectedIndexChanged()` method, and values are loaded in the controls to be update. But when I change the value from the controls to update the selected index in also called and throws `Index Out of Bounds -1 Exception`.

Here is my **SelectedIndexChanged Code**:

```
private void lst_items_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShoppingItem myItem = new ShoppingItem();
    if (lst_items.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        myItem = itemManager_obj.GetItem(lst_items.SelectedIndex);
        txt_amount.Text = myItem.amount.ToString();
        txt_description.Text = myItem.description;
        cmb_units.SelectedIndex = (int)myItem.unit;
    }
}
```

Here is my **Update(change) button** code:

```
    private void btn_change_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShoppingItem itemToChange = new ShoppingItem();
        itemToChange = itemManager_obj.GetItem(lst_items.SelectedIndex);

        bool success = false;

        itemToChange = ReadIput(out success);
        if (success)
        {
            success = itemManager_obj.ChangeItem(itemToChange,lst_items.SelectedIndex);
            lst_items.Items.RemoveAt(lst_items.SelectedIndex);
            lst_items.Items.Insert(lst_items.SelectedIndex, itemManager_obj.ToString());
            UpdateGUI();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why `SelectedIndexChanged` is called on update after this line of code is executed:

```
lst_items.Items.RemoveAt(lst_items.SelectedIndex);
```

Any idea how can I update without getting an exception index out of bound?
Regards

Comment: Any change in list triggers `SelectedIndexChanged` and there is reason for it. You could create `bool suspendListEvent = false` and when you populate it (at start of your button code) set it to true and at the end to false again. Now in event just add `if(suspendListEvent) return;`

Comment: @AleksaRistic thanks for the reply. I am not sure where to put this suspendListEvent variable...also i dont know why this selectedIndex becomes  -1 after this line gets executed.

         lst_items.Items.RemoveAt(lst_items.SelectedIndex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store this in an int

`lst_items.Items.RemoveAt(lst_items.SelectedIndex);`

then do

`lst_items.Items.Insert(your int, itemManager_obj.ToString());`

You are getting this error because after you remove the `selectedIndex`, there is no longer an item selected because that item doesn't exist.

```
 if (success)
 {
    int indexer=lst_items.SelectedIndex;
    success = itemManager_obj.ChangeItem(itemToChange,lst_items.SelectedIndex);
    lst_items.Items.RemoveAt(indexer);
    lst_items.Items.Insert(indexer, itemManager_obj.ToString());
    UpdateGUI();
 }
```

Comment: this RemoveAt is void functionof listbox.items and does not return an int.
Also there is no method of replace for listbox.items.

Comment: @TajamulIqbal try that

Comment: ..Thanks it worked. I also was trying this and then came back here to see, that was the same solution i made... :P
Anyhow bundle of thanks :)

Comment: you got it @TajamulIqbal! happy coding!